# SQL Case statement generating error in Visual studio report

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2008, dataset

Hi I am currently working with a report in Visual Studio 2008. I use the query below to create a data set. This works correctly in SQL / SMSS and in the dataset when I test the query.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN Make LIKE 'FO%' THEN 'Ford' 
     WHEN Make LIKE 'HON%' THEN 'Honda' 
END Make, 

CASE WHEN model LIKE 'CIV%' THEN 'Civic' 
     WHEN model LIKE '%AC%' THEN 'Accord'
     ELSE model 
END model, 
    year, AVG(Fuel.MPG) as AVGMPG
From cars, Fuel
Where Fuel.ID=cars.ID
    AND year > 2003
        AND Make is not NULL
            AND model is not NULL
                AND year is not NULL
    Group by Make, model, year
```

When I have a report reference the dataset it generates the following error;

> An error has occurred during report processing. Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation. Failed to enable constraints.
>   One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or
>   foreign-key constraints.

Since the actual SQL statement is larger and involves several CASE statements, all of which work, I have narrowed it down to the else portion of the statement.

For background, I am trying to pull all the data from model but group certain values that are similar, but still pull the rest of the data as well.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess here is that for some rows, the `model` column contains `null`, while the data set in your report does not allow `null` for the column value.

Comment: In the big query I have a Where statement i Have Model is not Null. Would that still cause a problem since that occurs after the case? I will modify the query to show the full scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN Make LIKE 'FO%' THEN 'Ford' 
     WHEN Make LIKE 'HON%' THEN 'Honda' 
END Make
```

With no default case, you'll end up with an error.  Change it to

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN Make LIKE 'FO%' THEN 'Ford' 
     WHEN Make LIKE 'HON%' THEN 'Honda'
     ELSE ''
END Make
```

Here's a quick way to find the column in error and the actual error:

```
var ds = new DataSet(); 
ds.EnforceConstraints = false;  
/* Fill dataset */  
try {  
   ds.EnforceConstraints = true;  
} catch {  
   foreach (DataTable tbl in ds.Tables) {  
      if (tbl.HasErrors) {  
         foreach (DataRow row in tbl.GetErrors()) {  
            foreach (DataColumn col in row.GetColumnsInError() {  
               row.GetColumnError(col); 
            }  
         }  
      }  
   }  
}
```

Comment: Hi so far the make CASE appears to work fine but I will add that to the query so as the data changes there will be no additional issues. The Model case is still giving me trouble. It's like the default case is not working with a report in visual studio.

Comment: I'd try to fill your dataset in a visual studio project, and use the `Datatable.GetErrors()` to track it down.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.geterrors.aspx)